# unity C# null reference exception when trying to add object to list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add object "newTask" to a list of builtTask objects called builtTasks.
I get error NullReferenceException pointing to builtTasks.Add(newTask). Debug.Logs returns the right values but it seems as if the code doesn't know that builtTasks actually exists. Please don't flame me I'm new to unity.
The class task has two values, a string and a string array. The class items has two values a string and a string array.
both arrays items and tasks were filled in unity itself. Please help me I don't get it

```
    public item[] items;
    public task[] tasks;
    private static List<builtTask> builtTasks;
    private static List<builtTask> runningTasks;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (builtTasks == null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            {

                string championName = tasks[i].championName;
                string itemName;
                List<item> items1 = new List<item> {};

                for (int j = 0; j < tasks[i].itemBuild.Length; j++) 
                {
                    itemName = tasks[i].itemBuild[j];
                    for( int k = 0; k < items.Length; k++)
                    {
                        if (itemName == items[k].itemName)
                        {
                            items1.Add(items[k]);
                            Debug.Log(items[k].itemName);
                        }
                    }

                }
                builtTask newTask = new builtTask(championName, items1.ToArray());
                Debug.Log(newTask.championName);
                Debug.Log(newTask.itemBuild[0].itemName);
                Debug.Log(newTask.itemBuild[1].itemName);
                Debug.Log(newTask.itemBuild[2].itemName);

                builtTasks.Add(newTask);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried fetching an object of class item from items array using a string tasks[i].itemBuild[j] and it works the Debug.Log returns right values of the constructed object newTask. But somehow I can't fill the object into builtTasks. I get NullReferenceException.

Comment: Seems like your builtTask has never been initialized. Your 'newTask' is actually OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a NullReference-exception because when trying to Add to the List, it is, in fact, null. You make that very clear in your check:

```
if (builtTasks == null)
```

You cannot call Add on a List-variable, whose value is null. You have to create an instance of that class, to be able to call methods on it - eigther when you declare the variable, or when you use it:

```
private static List<builtTask> builtTasks = new List<buildTask>();
```

The reason why it works for the "tasks" variable is likely, because it is a public field of a MonoBehaviour, which means its serialized by Unity (which includes initializing the value to a valid instance). A static variable does not have that luxurity, and you have to do it yourself. It's also a good idea to not use "public" for serialized variables, but instead mark them [SerializeField], and make them private if possible - this makes it clear that Unity is handling this field, both to you, as well as when yous how your code.

Comment: thank you very much didn't know that I thought I could use the if list == null to check if the list is empty

Comment: @Error020 Ah yes, those are different things. You can check "buildTasks.Count == 0" to see if an actual list is empty - though it has to be created first.